# Visual c++ icons in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

What icon below in my Visual Studio 2012 C++ project means?

[image]

Where I can find other icons meaning?

Answer (score 0):

I did find this page on Stackoverflow which seems to answer the same question you have: [Visual Studio Solution Explorer/Navigator Icons Meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496468/visual-studio-solution-explorer-navigator-icons-meaning)

The answers there lead to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245455%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with descriptions per icon. The style may have changed, but the icons still look alike. The one you displayed in the question should still have the "Excluded from source control" meaning.