# whats is this icon in visual studio source control?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have some files with these icons and i dont know what this means...
some help?
[image]

Comment: I think that icon means that the file is referenced by the project but doesn't actually exist (e.g. a file that will be created as part of another build step)

Comment: Files exists! All files referenced are in the folder with the other files.

Comment: Which source control system are you using?

Comment: im using github, and its the first time i see this!

Comment: I can't find that exact symbol now, so it's difficult to guess. Sometimes, the symbol (or the state of it) is just plain wrong.

Comment: Possibly relevant (or even a duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/38464552/10871073